# Replace multiple words with Str_Replace

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to replace multiple synonyms with one specific word.

```
<?p

$a = array(
'truck',
'vehicle',
'seddan',
'coupe',
'Toyota',
);
$b = array(
'car',
'car',
'car',
'car',
'Lexus',
);
$str = '

Honda is a truck. 
Toyota is a vehicle. 
Nissan is a sedan. 
Scion is a coupe.

';
echo str_replace($a,$b,$str);
?>
```

RESULT: Honda is a car. Lexus is a car. Nissan is a car. Scion is a car.

Can someone show me a clean way of replacing "vehicle, truck, coupe, sedan" with the word "car" instead of me replacing all 4 of them individually. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$a = array( 'truck', 'vehicle', 'sedan', 'coupe' );
$str = 'Honda is a truck. Toyota is a vehicle. Nissan is a sedan. Scion is a coupe.';
echo str_replace($a,'car',str_replace('Toyota','Lexus',$str));
```

Comment: that didnt seem to work. It doesnt replace the "truck" with "car"... The result ends up being "Honda is a car. Lexus is a . Nissan is a sedan. Scion is a ."

Comment: Updated my answer - second parameter must be a single string to allow multiple replacements. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can you please show me how I can correct this modified version of the code. http://codepad.org/DhPgwPCR Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should use [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

```
echo strtr($str,array_combine($a,$b));
```

Or Just combine `$a` and `$b` into one array

```
$ab = array('truck' => 'car','vehicle' => 'car','sedan' => 'var','coupe' => 'var','Toyota' => 'Lexus');
echo strtr($str, $ab);
```

Output

```
Honda is a car. 
Lexus is a car. 
Nissan is a car. 
Scion is a car.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a very  easy solution to replace multiple words in a string :

```
<?php
 $str="    Honda is a truck. 
Toyota is a vehicle. 
Nissan is a sedan. 
Scion is a coupe.";


$pattern=array();
$pattern[0]="truck";
$pattern[1]="vehicle";
$pattern[2]="sedan";
$pattern[3]="coupe";



$replacement=array();
$replacement[0]="car";
$replacement[1]="car";
$replacement[2]="car";
$replacement[3]="car";



echo str_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);?>
```

**output :**

```
  Honda is a car. 
Toyota is a car. 
Nissan is a car. 
Scion is a car
```

With this script you can replace as many words in a string as you want :

just place the word (that you want to replace) in the pattern array , eg :

```
     $pattern[0]="/replaceme/";
```

and place the characters (that will be used in place of the replaced characters) in the replacement array, eg :

```
      $replacement[0]="new_word";
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This example would also work with **preg_replace() function, delimite the pattern string if you want to use **preg_replace** instead of str_replace, eg: pattern[0]="/truck/";

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$a = array( 'truck', 'vehicle', 'seddan', 'coupe' ); 

$str = 'Honda is a truck. Toyota is a vehicle. Nissan is a sedan. Scion is a coupe.'; 

echo str_replace($a,'car',$str);
```

Should work.

http://codepad.org/1LhtcOSR

Edit:

Something like this should yield expected results: http://pastebin.com/xGzYiCk3

```
$text = '{test|test2|test3} some other stuff {some1|some2|some3}';
```

Output:

```
test3 some other stuff some1
test2 some other stuff some2
test3 some other stuff some3
test3 some other stuff some1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried giving you a vote up but its not letting me. I'm new here. can you please correct this code for me. http://codepad.org/DhPgwPCR thanks

Comment: You'll need to give a more detailed explanation of what it is you're trying to accomplish and I can help better :)

Comment: Okay so I use this website to "spin articles" to randomly select different words that are synonyms for example use "tale or story or storyline" in a random order everytime they appear in an article. http://ezarticlelink.com/articlespinner/free.php thats the website im using. try typing "The {story|tale|storyline} of the book is really nice." and you can see what I mean by spinning an article. But with the modified code it doesn't output it properly.

Comment: To get this type of functionality, you will need to write a parser that will parse the article (text) for your specified format {story|storyline|etc...} using one of the values at random. A simple str_replace won't work in this case.

Comment: The website does the randomizing.. The problem is that the script outputs and then replaces within that outputted value like "{story|{story|tale|{story|tale|storyline}}|{story|tale|storyline}}" instead of just doing it once like "{story|tale|storyline}"

Comment: thanks for the reply, that code was a little advanced for me so I'm not sure how to modify it lol can you show me how i can use it to get the actual result such as "The {story|tale|storyline} of the book is really nice. The {story|tale|storyline} starts with a boy. The {story|tale|storyline} progresses..."

Answer (score 1):

For replacing phrases with other phrases (multiple at a time). You can pass arrays as parameters to `str_replace()`

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = ["fruits", "vegetables", "fiber"];
$yummy   = ["pizza", "beer", "ice cream"];

$newPhrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this was possible